# Вывести данные связанных таблиц в select

Tags: yii2, select

Работаю с фреймворком YII2. Возник следующий вопрос, но обо всем по порядку.
Есть 3 таблицы в бд:

**Таблица хранящая название тем S_QUIZ_TOPIC с полями:**

```
integer $ID_REC
string $NAME_TOPIC
integer $RANDOM
integer $MAX_TIME
string $DT_UP
integer $STATUS
```

**Таблица хранящая вопросы S_QUIZ_QUESTION с полями:**

```
integer $ID_REC
string $NAME_QUEST
string $TEXT_QUEST
string $MSG_QUEST
integer $RANDOM
string $DT_UP
integer $STATUS
```

**И связывающая эти 2 таблицы S_QUIZ_TQ:**

```
integer $ID_REC
integer $ID_TOPIC
integer $ID_QUESTION
string $DT_UP
integer $STATUS
```

Для каждой таблицы сгенерированы модели.
Для **S_QUIZ_TOPIC** и **S_QUIZ_QUESTION** сгенерированы контроллеры и представления в CRUD. Задание следующее: при просмотре какой либо темы (страница view, представление **S_QUIZ_TOPIC**) нужно каким то образом вывести 2 таблицы следующего содержания:
1) В первой таблице выведен список с названием всех вопросов, которые не входят в эту тему.
2) Во второй таблице выведен список с названиями всех вопросов, которые входят в эту тему.

Для начала я использовал обычную GridView для вывода данных в эти таблицы. Все что мне пришлось добавить, это функцию в модель **S_QUIZ_TOPIC**:

```
public function getQuestions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SQuizQuestion::className(), ['ID_REC' => 'ID_QUESTION'])->via('sQUIZTQs');
}
```

И в контроллер **S_QUIZ_TOPIC**:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $searchModel = new SQuizQuestionSearch();
    $dataProviderLeft = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProviderRight = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $model->getQuestions(),
    ]);

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProviderLeft' => $dataProviderLeft,
        'dataProviderRight' => $dataProviderRight,
    ]);
}
```

После чего во view файле я вывел данные таблицы следующим образом:

**Для 1-й таблицы:**

```
<?= 
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderLeft,
        'columns' => [
            [
                    'attribute' => 'NAME_QUEST',
                    'label' => 'Список выбранных вопросов',
                ],
        ],
]); 
?>
```

**Для 2-й таблицы:**

```
<?= 
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderRight,
        'columns' => [
            [
                    'attribute' => 'NAME_QUEST',
                    'label' => 'Список выбранных вопросов',
                ],
        ],
]); 
?>
```

Все выводилось правильно. В левой таблицы был список всех вопросов, в правой не было ни одного вопроса. Теперь мне понадобилось переделать это и вывести данные не через GridView, а через select. Для первой таблицы я сделал это следующим образом:

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
       <input id="search-avaliable">
       <a href="#" id="btn-refresh"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> </a> <br>
       <?= Html::activeDropDownList($modelquest, 'ID_REC', $items, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%']) ?>
</div>
```

У меня вывелся список всех вопросов. А как сделать это для второй таблицы, в которой нужно выводить только вопросы, которые входят в эту тему? С GridView все было понятно, сделал функцию и через dataProvider все выводилось легко, а как тут быть? Как не пытался, у меня либо выскакивает ошибка, либо опять все вопросы выводятся.

**Фото как выглядят таблицы:**
[image: Фото]

Comment: Так точно так же, у вас же работает $dataProviderRight. По левому селекту делаете экшн с параметром фильтрации для правого (id левого селекта). Потом $rightItems = ArrayHelper::map($dataProviderRight->getModels(), 'ID_REC', 'NAME_QUEST'); и создаете такой же dropdown. Чтобы все работало без перезагрузки оборачиваете их в Pjax.

Comment: @onmotion точно, дошло, спасибо за подсказку)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Код контроллера:**

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $searchModel = new SQuizQuestionSearch();
    $dataProviderLeft = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProviderRight = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $model->getQuestions(),
    ]);

    $leftitems = ArrayHelper::map($dataProviderLeft->getModels(),'ID_REC','NAME_QUEST');
    $rightItems = ArrayHelper::map($dataProviderRight->getModels(), 'ID_REC', 'NAME_QUEST');

    return $this->render('view', [

        'model' => $model,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,

        'dataProviderLeft' => $dataProviderLeft,
        'leftitems' => $leftitems,

        'dataProviderRight' => $dataProviderRight,
        'rightItems' => $rightItems,
    ]);
}
```

**Левая таблица:**

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
       <h4>Вопросы не входящие в эту тему</h4>
              <input id="search-avaliable">
              <a href="#" id="btn-refresh"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> </a> <br>
              <?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'ID_REC', $leftitems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%']) ?>
</div>
```

**Правая таблица:**

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
       <h4>Вопросы не входящие в эту тему</h4>
              <input id="search-avaliable">
              <a href="#" id="btn-refresh"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> </a> <br>
              <?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'ID_REC', $rightitems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%']) ?>
</div>
```